# Conditional expression in a function?

Tags: r

Is it possible to include a conditional (if, else) expression in R into a function?

My code looks like this, but I'm getting errors back:

```
Myfunction <- function(Arg1, Arg2) {
    if(Arg1="condition1"){
        # ...
    } else {
        # ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Equality is tested with `==`; you are performing an assignment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is allowed ...

```
MyFunction<-function(Arg1,Arg2) 
{ 
   if(Arg1=="data") { 
       print("i am in if") 
   }
   else
   { 
       print("i am in else") 
   }
}
```

as mentioned by @nrussel it is `"=="` operator that you seems to be missing in while checking `IF` condition